# Arrange the products in descending order of thier MFG_DATE. In case of same MFG_DATE arrange them in descending order of their PRICE

Tags: sql, oracle

Can some one please tell me the correct way to write a SQL statement for the above Question.

I am doing this, but it shows Sql command not properly ended. I am using SQL *PLUS.

`PRODUCT` is the table name.

```
SELECT PROD_NAME FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY MFG_DATE DESC
(SELECT PROD_NAME FROM PRODUCT GROUP BY PRICE HAVING 
COUNT(MFG_DATE)>1 
ORDER BY 
MFG_DATE DESC)
```

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. Tagging completely irrelevant technologies just wastes the time of the subject experts you attract that know nothing about the technology you are *actually* asking about. Either way, tag spam can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about. I've removed all the conflicting tags.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that regardless of dialect, an `AND` *after* an expresison defined in the `ORDER BY` clause is never allowed. I have no idea what that `AND` clause is meant to be achieving.

Comment: If two products have the same manufacturing date and the same price, how do you order them? (What is the next tie-breaker, the same way that price is the tie-breaker if the manufacturing date is the same?)

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right, all you need to do is to specify the "price" column on the second place in the order by part:

```
select *
  from product
 order by mfg_date desc, price desc;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a67998e8791801aa88e1fdaf53cbf84a)

Answer (score 1):

The way you explained it in the title, that would be

```
select prod_name
from product
order by mfg_date, price desc
```

---

(BTW, this is Oracle; SQL*Plus is its command-line tool).